# Searching Contents in Firebase Live Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When I search for items in my firebase database, I am not getting an error but instead no value at all. When going through the debugger, the values I have in the editText are infact being set and when searching for those values in the Query, they aren't showing up:

```
final EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DjNameET);

        mProfileDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        t.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
                {
                    searchData = t.getText().toString();


                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ImageButton imgB= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);

        imgB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                query = mProfileDatabase.child("djprofile").orderByChild("djName")
                        .startAt(searchData)
                        .endAt(searchData + "\uf8ff");

                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DjProfile> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DjProfile>()
                        .setQuery(query, DjProfile.class)
                        .build();
                firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DjProfile, ResultsViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions)
                {

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ResultsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.searchitem_list, viewGroup, false);

                        return new ResultsViewHolder(view);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ResultsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DjProfile model) {
                        holder.setDjProfile(model);
                    }
                };
                firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
            }
        });
```

Here is what the live database looks like:

[image]

In my edit text when I search for "DjRockSauce" no results are shown within the recyclerview, I have a feeling this is because I am not getting the correct path into the query, if this is the case how do I correctly get the file paths for searching and displaying results?

Comment: The `mProfileDatabase.child("djprofile").orderByChild("djName")` looks good to me. If you remove the `orderByChild().startAt().endAt()`, does it show all child nodes?

Comment: Yes it does, I just checked now

Comment: So in that case the path is correct, and the problem is in the order/filter. If you hardcode the search terms (so `.orderByChild("djName").startAt("Dj").endAt("Dj\uf8ff");`), does it work?

Comment: Ha! Yes that also works

Comment: I printed a toast message of the string I am passing through to my startAt() and endAt() methods and it is null, I am going to find a way to get the actual value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a problem like this, the right approach is to try to find where the problem is, *and* where it *isn't*.

The first step could be to see if you can show the unfiltered profiles.

```
query = mProfileDatabase.child("djprofile");
```

If this shows all profiles, you know that the path you build is correct.

If that is the case, I'd try with a hard-coded search string:

```
query = mProfileDatabase.child("djprofile").orderByChild("djName")
        .startAt("Dr")
        .endAt("Dr\uf8ff");
```

If that works too, the problem is in how you get the search term, and you should be looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out with the help of @Frank van Puffelen, that my issue was I was calling searchText, and it was returning null. When in fact I needed to pass the physical EditText name's text into the search query as follows:

```
            query = mProfileDatabase.child("djprofile").orderByChild("djName")
                    .startAt(t.getText().toString()).endAt(t.getText().toString() + "\uf8ff");
```